# Plans for black in Pirc when white responds to e5 with d5

Tags: kings-indian, planning, pirc-defense, modern-defense

Intuitively I would think that this line should just be a better (for black) version of the usual Mar Del Plata KID, seeing that the white c pawn is less advanced and the knight is somewhat passively placed on d2, and that black therefore should simply go on with the usual f5 push. However, in the few practical games I've had, this has not worked out for me so well, and I see the engine is actually recommending c6 (after many logical next moves from white), which strikes me as a tad odd position ally. Is there somehow something in this position that makes the f5 plan less attractive than in the Mar Del Plata?

```
[FEN "r1bq1rk1/ppp1npbp/3p1np1/3Pp3/4P3/2PB1N2/PP1N1PPP/R1BQ1RK1 w - - 1 9"]
1. e4 g6 2. d4 Bg7 3. Nf3 d6 4. c3 Nf6 5. Nbd2 O-O 6. Bc4 Nc6 7. O-O e5 8. d5 Ne7
```

Answer (score 2):

Engines don't like philosophy behind KID and if they are forced to play KID, they play c6 there all day long too. Here it's quite similar. You can play for both plans but I see nothing wrong with the f5 ideas. It seems to be much better version of main line KID.